# Python make more scalable of a given list products

Tags: python

I would like to find a way for the possible products of the given list. 
Basically the index can be followed by a number that is next to that number such as A1A2,A2C3... or circular number A3D1, D3B1... Below, I have an example

An example:

```
the_list=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']
The results should be: 
['A1A2','A1B2','A1C2','A1D2','A2A3','A2B3','A2C3','A2D3','A3A1','A3B1','A3C1','A3D1'
 'B1A2,'B2A3'...
 'C1A2'...']
```

So far, I tried this :

```
the_list=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']
result=[]
for i in range(len(the_list)):
    for k in range((i%3+1),len(the_list)+1,3):
        s=str(the_list[i])+str(the_list[k%len(the_list)])
        result.append(s)
```

Output:

```
['A1A2', 'A1B2', 'A1C2', 'A1D2', 'A2A3', 'A2B3', 'A2C3', 'A2D3', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 
    'A3D1', 'A3A1', 'B1A2', 'B1B2', 'B1C2', 'B1D2', 'B2A3', 'B2B3', 'B2C3', 'B2D3', 'B3B1', 
    'B3C1', 'B3D1', 'B3A1', 'C1A2', 'C1B2', 'C1C2', 'C1D2', 'C2A3', 'C2B3', 'C2C3', 'C2D3', 
    'C3B1', 'C3C1', 'C3D1', 'C3A1', 'D1A2', 'D1B2', 'D1C2', 'D1D2', 'D2A3', 'D2B3', 'D2C3', 
    'D2D3', 'D3B1', 'D3C1', 'D3D1', 'D3A1']
```

This works fine. But, I want to make it more scalable, so far it generates two sequences like A1A2, A1D2... How can i change my code to make it scalable? So, if the scale is 3, it should generate A1A2A3,... in the same manner.

Update: I think there should be one more for loop that takes care of the size and accumulates the sequence based on that number, but I could not figure it out so far how to.

Comment: If I read the results correctly - anything "connected" (if viewed as a grid) - either horizontally/vertically/diagonally is a candidate?

Comment: Nevermind - think I over analysed a bit - look at `itertools` as @Amber has suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `numbers = IT.cycle(numbers)` to generate the sequence of valid
  numbers. [By making it a cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), you do not have to treat `1` following `3` any different than `2` following `1`.
- The letters in each item can be generated by [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). The
  `repeat` parameter is especially useful here. It will allow you to,
  as you say, "scale" the generator to longer sequences with no
  additional effort.
- You can use `zip` to combine the letters generated by
  `itertools.product` (called `lets` below) with the `numbers` from
  `itertools.cycle`.
- `''.join(IT.chain.from_iterable` is [just a way to join the list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) of
  tuples returned by `zip` into a string.

---

```
import itertools as IT

def neighbor_product(letters, numbers, repeat = 2):
    N = len(numbers)
    numbers = collections.deque(numbers)
    for lets in IT.product(letters, repeat = repeat):
        for i in range(N):
            yield ''.join(IT.chain.from_iterable(zip(lets, IT.cycle(numbers))))
            numbers.rotate(-1)

letters = 'ABCD'
numbers = '123'
for item in neighbor_product(letters, numbers, repeat = 3):
    print(item)
```

yields

```
A1A2A3
A2A3A1
A3A1A2
A1A2B3
...
D3D1C2
D1D2D3
D2D3D1
D3D1D2
```

Comment: This won't generate anything like `?2?3?1`, though, and if I understand the generalization then it should.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks; indeed there was an error in my code. I forgot to advance `number` `N` times so each possible sequence of numbers is enumerated. I hope this was the error you were referring to :)

Comment: How to modify your code to generate two digit numbers like 11, 12 ?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Change `numbers` to a list of strings, such as `numbers = ['11','12']`.

Comment: but, when I start the numbers from 0, like numbers=['0','1' ..'9'], it is not generating correct sequences, Why?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes, you are right -- my way of advancing `numbers` was not guaranteed to hit every number once. I think it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after.

```
import itertools

def products(letters='ABCD', N=3, scale=2):
    for lets in itertools.product(letters, repeat=scale):
        for j in xrange(N):
            yield ''.join('%s%d' % (c, (i + j) % N + 1)
                          for i, c in enumerate(lets))

print list(products(scale=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

**result=[i+j for i in the_list for j in the_list]**

Comment: This produces combinations such as `'A1A1', 'A2A2', 'C2C2'` etc. which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: then get this : **result=[i+j for i in the_list for j in the_list if i!=j]**

Comment: This gives all permutations but doesn't filter them according to the criteria the OP wants. Also, `itertools.permutations(the_list, 2)` is more efficient than your list comprehension. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use Python's standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a subset of all possible permutations. [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) returns a generator of all permutations as n-sized tuples for a given sequence and a given length n. I would iterate over all permutations and filter them based on your criteria. What about this:

```
In [1]: from itertools import permutations

In [2]: the_list = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3','D1','D2','D3']

In [3]: results = []

In [4]: digits = list(set([elem[1] for elem in the_list]))

In [5]: digits
Out[5]: ['1', '2', '3']

In [6]: for perm in permutations(the_list, 2):
  ....:     if (int(perm[0][1])+1 == int(perm[1][1]) or 
  ....:        (perm[0][1] == digits[-1] and perm[1][1] == digits[0])): 
  ....:         results.append(''.join(perm))

In [7]: sorted(results)
Out[7]: ['A1A2', 'A1B2', 'A1C2', 'A1D2', 'A2A3', 'A2B3', 'A2C3', 
         'A2D3', 'A3A1', 'A3B1', 'A3C1', 'A3D1', 'B1A2', 'B1B2', 
         'B1C2', 'B1D2', 'B2A3', 'B2B3', 'B2C3', 'B2D3', 'B3A1', 
         'B3B1', 'B3C1', 'B3D1', 'C1A2', 'C1B2', 'C1C2', 'C1D2', 
         'C2A3', 'C2B3', 'C2C3', 'C2D3', 'C3A1', 'C3B1', 'C3C1', 
         'C3D1', 'D1A2', 'D1B2', 'D1C2', 'D1D2', 'D2A3', 'D2B3', 
         'D2C3', 'D2D3', 'D3A1', 'D3B1', 'D3C1', 'D3D1']
```

Comment: A1A3 is not valid for my case!

Comment: @JohnSmith I've edited my solution. Please look at it again. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, but it should be more scalable, your is limited only two sequence. for ex, more scale like A1A2A3A4A5...

Answer (score 0):

Since not every combination is valid according to your specifications, checking every possible combination and discarding invalid ones may not be the best approach here.

Since the number of each item is important for determining whether a combination is valid, let's create a lookup table for that first:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for item in the_list:
    lookup[int(item[1])].append(item)
```

This makes it easy to get all items with a specific number (which will be useful when we want to get the items for consequtive numbers):

```
lookup[1] == ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']
```

Creating all valid combinations can now be done as following:

```
from itertools import product

def valid_combinations(lookup):
    min_number = min(lookup)
    max_number = max(lookup)
    for number in lookup:
        # Let's just assume here that we've only got consecutive numbers, no gaps:
        next_number = min_number if number == max_number else number + 1
        for combination in product(lookup[number], lookup[next_number]):
            yield ''.join(combination)
```

To allow any number of items to be chained, we'll need to modify that a bit:

```
def valid_combinations(lookup, scale = 2):
    min_number = min(lookup)
    max_number = max(lookup)
    def wrap_number(n):
        while n > max_number:
            n -= max_number + 1 - min_number
        return n
    for number in lookup:
        numbers = list(wrap_number(n) for n in range(number, number + scale))
        items = [lookup[n] for n in numbers]
        for combination in product(*items):
            yield ''.join(combination)
```

For scale 5, this would produce the following results (showing only the first few of a total of 3072):

```
['A1A2A3A1A2', 'A1A2A3A1B2', 'A1A2A3A1C2', 'A1A2A3A1D2', 'A1A2A3B1A2', ...]
```